# Is Java ready for a HashCode record?

Tags: java, hashcode, jit, java-record

Records represent immutable state and are candidates for stack inlining.

If I declare a draft outline of a HashCode record, similar to a message digest class, like so:

```
public record HashCode(int value) {
    HashCode update(int value) {
        return new HashCode(value() * 31 + value);
    }
    // ... other update convenience methods here
}
```

Will the JIT immediately unroll HashCode instances onto the stack for the following approach to hashCode generation?

```
HashCode hashCode = new HashCode(0);
for (Object field : fields) {
    hashCode = hashCode.update(field.hashCode());
}
hash = hashCode.value();
```

Or will I encounter pitfalls like unnecessary object churn?

This record definition seems like a silver bullet approach to efficient inline hashCode generation.

Are there any downsides to this approach?

I recognise that hashCode generation can be influenced by prior knowledge of the distribution of the data being hashed, but this record seems like a drop in replacement for the multiply and add code that's repeated everywhere, and could even be accommodating to any kind of update, for example other methods could update via xoring etc.

I'm going to try the above HashCode record but I only like to embrace higher level idioms if I fully understand the tradeoffs I'm making between usability and performance.

Comment: I think this will be pretty inefficient. Why not just use [`Objects.hash(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#hash(java.lang.Object...))

Comment: @MarkRotteveel That boxes primitives and allocates an array.

Comment: That is still likely to be more efficient and optimizable than trying to create a lot of records.

Comment: In my experience, the JVM is pretty bad at optimizing away object creation like this, especially in a loop.  You could probably micro-benchmark this and see if the version involving only primitives runs faster... (Or the reflection might dominate the loop overhead and the object creation might not matter.)

Comment: With proper stack allocation, method inlining and live register analysis, the HashCode record should generate identical instructions to a primitive multiply/add for loop.  I'm not familiar with Java's performance / inlining guarantees when it comes to records, but I'm familiar with the compiler optimisations available.

Comment: @Boann the JIT might be at liberty to inline and unroll the array to the stack too, but I suspect records are more likely to be optimised this way.

Comment: @markspace remember these are records, and their immutability contract begs for them to be inlined by the JIT, I don't know what guarantees there are.  Certainly the objects never leave the method. and only one object is alive at a time, so the same stack area can used for all instances, meaning it should translate to a single int value; on the stack, with an inlined update() assignment;

Comment: @MarkRotteveel My point is, with even the most rudamentary of jit analysis, no records should ever be created on the heap. A combination of stack inlining, live variable analysis and method inlining will very quickly reduce this to the multiply-and-add for loops that we commonly see for hashcode generation.

Comment: @Boann the OP’s code has already an array of objects, so passing that to `Objects.hash(…)` has no overhead at all.

Comment: @Holger How many hashCode methods have you ever written where each field was already boxed and all were in an array?

Comment: @Boann I’m specifically referring to the OP’s loop in this question we’re all commenting. If you have actual distinct fields rather than such an array, there is no problem in using the right idiom for each field, i.e. 1) just use the value for integer types, 2) Use [`Double.hashCode(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#hashCode(double)) etc. for the non-integer primitive types 3) use `object.hashCode()` only for actual objects. Then, if you don’t have an array, you don’t have a loop, so you might just write `((a * 31) + b) * 31 + c`, etc.

Comment: @Boann or just use a `record` in the first place which gets an appropriate `hashCode()` method for free.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found my answer in another stackoverflow post: [Are Java records stack allocated like C# structs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64756584/are-java-records-stack-allocated-like-c-sharp-structs) There are upcoming proposals for Value types, which will achieve this via Scalarization:

> In C2, value objects on the stack are typically scalarized when stored or passed with concrete value class types. Scalarization effectively encodes each field as a separate variable, with an additional variable encoding null; no heap allocation is needed.

and

> Record classes will be able to be declared as value or primitive types to support this sort of stack allocation, but are not required to be.

So record types are not the intended solution to this.

Comment: So basically you are saying that as currently implemented, records may not be aggressively inlined or converted to memory on the stack, there's a real chance that the JVM just allocates the records on the heap instead?

Comment: Yes, from the JEP 401 draft: "Previously, JVMs have used similar optimization techniques to inline identity objects when the JVM is able to prove that an object's identity is never used. Developers can expect more predictable and widespread optimizations for value objects."

Comment: I also like this comment they made in the draft: "Hand-coded optimizations via basic primitive values are possible to improve performance, but as noted in the "Motivation" section, these techniques require giving up valuable abstractions." echoes my sentiments exactly.

Comment: There's more changes in the pipeline though.  Value objects don't have object identity, but are nullable, and in C1 they are still allocated on the heap.  There's further work to introduce primitive types, which will occupy precisely the memory footprint of their fields.  There's changes to facilitate interoperability in the context of identity objects, so if `primitive class HashCode` is equivalent to `int`, `HashCode.ref` is the value class equivalent to `Integer`.  These changes are still in the Candidate state though, so there's no commitment to deliver these in any particular release.